c# FLAUI execution blocked by dialog window
I've faced with and strange behavior of FLAUI - it stuck when dialog box come up:
TreeItem item = mainWindow.FindFirstByXPath("//TreeItem[@Name='MY Item']").AsTreeItem();
item.Expand(); // dialog box come up after this action
Console.WriteLine("END."); // this line never reached

I have tried to create separate thread which will connect to application, find dialog box and click it's button. but it can't find a dialog box...
Are there any ways to fix that behavior?
